# Raspberry PHP script runs out of RAM

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi

I wrote a php script, which reads data from a file and calculates sums and averages. If I run the script on my Xampp Apache Webserver on my Desktop PC there are no problems. In the php.ini file I defined `memory_limit=256M`. On the Raspberry-Pi I installed the apache webserver with the php5 package. If I run the script on my RasPi I get:

`Fatal error:  Allowed memory size exhausted`

I tried to increase the `memory_limit`, but I still get the same error message.
Why uses the script more memory on the RasPi than on Windows?

Edit: [that's the script](https://github.com/qwertz1029384756/fhemphp/blob/master/index.php)

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code. I'm pretty sure there will be a big amount of room for optimization.

Comment: Without knowing what your script does, it's hard to say. Most PHP processes can run in 32-64M of RAM. 256 is a LOT, and on a Raspberry Pi that's either half or all the available RAM on the system period.

Comment: @André Daniel I added a link to the script

Comment: try to do not load all records to an array, instead, process all data, directly from the row read from the database.

Comment: You could do a lot of optimization on that script. Have you tried running it on your own system or clean vps and checked what the actual values were (RAM and CPU etc.)?

Comment: After having taken a look at your script in Intellij, there is some stuff that needs improvement. First of all, don't fetch every single record in an array and then start iterating though them. Reason for this, is because the Garbage collector can't do it's job since there are still references to the entities in the array so all those entities remain loaded in memory, throughout the whole execution. You are doing this multiple times in the program so take a look at those and try to fetch, process and repeat instead of fetch all and then process.

Comment: arquitectures are different and can justify the issue, but anyway are you using the same database? with same # of records? Notice that in fact you arrive to an unestable design, even if it fits now, what if DB grows? again: do not load all records to memory!

Comment: @LuisSiquot I am currently testing with one DB entry. The DB is comtletely the same. The DB sets only the paths to the files to load.

Comment: does the error provide the line where it occurs?  I bet it is on line 16 or 17.

Comment: @LuisSiquot `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in /var/www/index.php on line 70` ` foreach($zeilen as $zeile)
 {
  $days[] = explode(" ", $zeile);
 }`

Comment: well 536870912 exacly maches 512Mb. That means that either the OS or PHP itself has imposed this limit. I do not remember now, but raspberry pi OS, do not uses swap partition (this destroys your SD). Also, don't remember but isn't 512 the total memory on it? line 70 is again against memory, loading full content of an array into another.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that comes to my mind is that you have other processes eating up your memory on Raspberry,
try checking memory in use with `/proc/meminfo` or `free -m` command_